# Por que se fala “esteja” e não “esteje”?

Tags: etimologia

Os verbos da primeira conjugação (*amar*, *matar*) terminam em e no presente do subjuntivo (*ame*, *mate*), e os verbos da segunda e terceira conjugação (*bater*, *definir*) terminam em a no presente do subjuntivo (*bata*, *defina*). Isto se aplica até a verbos irregulares: *s**er*** → *sej**a***, *pôr* (ant. *poer*) → *ponh**a***, *t**er*** → *tenh**a***.

O verbo *estar* já não: *est**ar*** → *estej**a***, tanto há quem fala *esteje*. No latim, o presente do subjuntivo era *stem*, *stes*, *stet*, sem nenhum *a*.

Por que o verbo *estar* tem seu presente do subjuntivo terminando em *a*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do latim o que nos veio foi *estê* (de [*stem* e *stet*](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/verb:stare)) e não *esteje*.  Diz Manoel Said Ali (*Gramática Histórica da Língua Portuguesa,* 2ª edição, Rio de Janeiro, 1931, p.  160) que *esteja*, etc. foi influência do *seja* (grafia original):

> De *estar, estou,* usou-se em port[uguês] ant[igo] e entre os quinhentistas a formação regular: *estê, estês, estê, estemos, esteis, estêm* (*estêem*). Por infuencia de *seja* alterou-se depois *estê* em *esteja,* que suplantou de todo a antiga forma.

As formas antigas têm a terminação em -*e*- típica dos verbos da primeira conjugação (terminados em -*ar*) e vieram-nos com alteração mínima do latim:

> **Presente do subjuntivo/conjuntivo**
>                      [**Latim**](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/verb:stare)             **Português antigo**            **Português atual**
> Eu                 stem                       estê                                 esteja
> Tu                 stes                         estês                               estejas
> Ele                stet                          estê                                esteja
> Nós              stemos                     estemos                         estejamos
> Vós               stetis                        esteis                             estejais
> Eles              stent                          estêm                             estejam